# Как сделать программу-фильтр для потока видео?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, видео

Есть **поток** видео. То есть, **бесконечный**.

В видео могут быть места, которые нужно будет размыть. ну, например, надпись "идите все на ..." на заборе.

**Самописная программа** должна в реальном анализировать поток видео, который ей поступает на вход, и если там есть забор и такая надпись, размывать надпись. И выдавать это же видео с размытой надписью.

Или просто видео без изменений, если там нет этого.

То есть, как фильтр.

Как примерно это можно сделать? куда копать?

Comment: В такой формулировке - никак. Если видео предварительно размечено и параллельно с потоком идёт какая-то метаинформация о том, по каким координатам нужно делать размытие - то ещё можно что-то придумать.

Comment: @Александр, ну почему, распознать ведь можно? обучить.

Comment: берете нейронную сеть для распознавания текста, сраниваете текст с шаблоном, и если сходиться размываете. Проблемы?

Comment: @Александр [Real Time Text-Recognition.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvBH5aakt_A) (OpenCV)